# Can Shorinji Kempo's Uwa-Uke Block be performed in a Yin Manner?

Tags: shorinji-kempo

When I studied shorinji kempo one of my instructors (now passed away) taught me a 'yin' style of performing the Soto-Oshi-Uke Block.

This block for those unaware is against a curved Fri-zuki attack.  The beginner way of doing this block is to meet the force at right angles as shown in figure 1.  [image: Figure 1]

However the more advanced 'yin' version of this block involves contacting the incoming blow at a different angle. Figure 2 [image: Figure 2]

The result of this small change in angle is that the attacker (Tori) will come to kesushi and sometimes topple.  Alternatively they will have to step.  This superior blocking method allows a more time for the counter attack so makes your subsequent attack more effective.

My question is: Is there a way in which Uwa-Uke, (the upwards block usually used against downwards or straight attacks) can be performed in this 'Yin' style to have the same effect?  Will this work on both gyaku-zuki and shito-zuki attacks or only one or the other?
Similarly will it work on both advancing forms of the block (as in Uwa-Uke-Zuki) or only in retreating forms (as in Uwa-Uke-Geri Omotte)?

Edit: I have realised a video might be helpful.  This shows the yin block.  https://youtu.be/Z8WSpU8lM3I?t=63

And here is the beginner 'yang' block https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soasaSCrR_I

Comment: I imagine this question should be answerable by a non-Shoriji-Kempo practitioner if you also provide translations.

Comment: The translations don't really mean anything. They are just technique names. I guess I could find videos of them.

Comment: Gyaku zuki = reverse punch?

Comment: Back hand punch.  But yes reverse punch is the literal translation.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was that the translations of the names would be helpful. I know what a back hand punch is, but I don't know what a gyaku zuki is. This contrasts with translations like "monkey stealing peaches", where the translation is truly just a name.

Comment: I understand that, unfortunately translation literal or otherwise are not always possible. These techniques are not descriptive. It is similar to trying to translate seotoshi from judo. You can translate the names but not the meaning.

Comment: Soto oshi uke for example is something like outwards pushing receive.

Comment: I will say though that if I understand your yin version of soto oshi uke, the key characteristic is reaching out earlier to deflect and having the hand pull back with the attack, which can be used to control and destabalise.  That approach is definitely viable in an upward block: just reach further earlier then guide the attacker for longer.  If they're delivering a downward strike it's easy to pull them off to the side and their weight onto the front foot.  For a punch, the same principle applies: reach forward, grasp near the elbow, deflect sideways and pull the elbow down into your control.

Comment: I do not understand the seotoshi (shoulder drop) comparison; that is a straightforward description of the throw in non-flowery language. Yama arashi (mountain storm) is an example of a technique where the translation does not help. Which category are we in?

Comment: @mattm You don't drop your own shoulder when you perform seotoshi.  And if you asked a japanese person who knew nothing of judo to seotoshi they would look at you blankly.  These are not descriptive at all.  They may give clues to the trained but I could translate the entirety of this and you still be none the wiser.

Comment: @Tony D.  We never use Uwa-Uke against anything other than attacks to the head and neck.  These are common enough and the technique is good for this.

Comment: @TonyD You don't reach out any earlier and if you grab we have a different name for the block.  The yin version is simply the same block with the direction of forced changed.  It's not easy to do.  Also you don't grasp the elbow, you have to block the wrist in every case.

Comment: @HuwEvans: If someone has their arm chambered ready to punch - any telegraphing and stepping will happen before you can tell whether they're punching to the ribs or head - and if you wait until they're throwing the punch with your hand down low ready to raise it into the block, you're asking for trouble IMHO.

Comment: @TonyD we have no issue learning the ability to read attacks in this manner. Bear in mind we stand further appart than karateka would.  Hence blocking the wrist.

Comment: @HuwEvans: I'm not sure how that would hold up for self defence; good fighters only throw committed punches when they're anticipating they might hit, and given the speed of footwork vs punching, won't punch if you're at wrist-to-wrist distance.  Cooperative exercises are a different world.  But anyway, seems hard to communicate our respective points in writing - would be fun if we were close enough to train together, but I'm giving up on this one.  Cheers

Comment: @TonyD It's possible the founder of kyukoshin felt the same way.  I heard He once trained SK but left to found his own style.  But this is how we train in any case:  Luring our attackers to come within distance and dodging, blocking, shifting weight and stepping as they close.  The idea here is that this block should stop the attacker and leave them in place on the tips of their toes.  We never maintain the distance where we can be hit for long except when we are striking.